# Check for distinct column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table named **Person** which has three columns **Name, Designation, Address**.

I need to find for a unique combination of Name and Designation if address gets repeated, if yes I need to get mark as `true` else `false`.

Sample:

```
Name   Designation   Address
Alex     Manager     Houston
Alex     Manager     Houston
Bailey   Worker      Boston
Bailey   Worker      New York

O/P:
Name   Designation  Repeated 
Alex   Manager       true
Bailey Worker        false
```

I know until a point where I can group columns, I tried like this

```
select Name, Designation, Address
from Person 
group by Name, Designation, Address
```

Edit : If Alex has address "**Phoenix**" , then also the result would be the same i.e., Repeated column is "**true**" as already Alex has "**Houston**" repeated in two rows.

Comment: Maybe check for the count after grouping, if greater than 1 then true else false

Comment: What do you mean by "repeated"?  What if Alex had a third row in Phoenix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeated means that the number of distinct addresses does not match the total.  So:

```
select name, designation,
       (case when count(distinct Address) < count(*) then 'true' else 'false') as is_repeated
from person
group by name, designation;
```

Comment: I can see from the variety of answers that our reading of what "repeated" means is not clear!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below way -

```
select Name,Designation,case when count(distinct Address)=1 then 'true' else 'false' end as repeated 
from Person 
group by Name,Designation
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple group by and count:

```
select Name, Designation, case when count(*)>1 then 'true' else 'false' end as Repeated
from Person
group by Name, Designation
```

Comment: `when count(*)>1 then 'true'` ??? It will return true for both the records.

Comment: As far as I can see thats what the OP wants. @Tejash

Answer (score 0):

And just because there's always more than one way to write a query:

```sql
WITH cte_Counts AS
(
    SELECT      [Name]
                , [Designation]
                , [Address]
                , COUNT(*) AS [Count]
    FROM        Person
    GROUP BY    [Name]
                , [Designation]
                , [Address]
)
SELECT      [Name]
            , [Designation]
            , CASE
                WHEN [Count] > 1
                    THEN    'true'
                ELSE        'false'
            END AS [Repeated]
FROM        cte_Counts ;
```